# Change internal voltage reference on an STM32L0

Tags: adc, stm32, mbed, accuracy, nucleo

I'm using a Nucleo board with an STM32L073RZ. With an "AnalogIn" object on PA_0, I measure the voltage of a TMP36 (temperature sensor), but the accuracy is not great at low temperature.

I want to change the internal voltage reference to get better accuracy. After a lot of search I haven't found anything. How can I change that on my STM32?

EDIT: On the screen below you can see result of multiple measure of the same voltage obtained with AC laboratory power supply.
[image: Read value in function of the number of measures]

Comment: What do you mean by change the internal reference?

Comment: I mean change the internal voltage for the ADC. For example if I want to measure voltage around 500mV on my pin, I can reduce this internal ref to 1.5v to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the internal reference voltage, \$ V_{REFINT} \$, as it's a band gap device fixed at about 1.22V. But the ADC range is from 0 to \$ V_{REF+} \$ anyway, and unless you have a pin available for \$ V_{REF+} \$, which you probably haven't on the version of that processor fitted to the Nucleo board, it will be tied to \$ V_{DDA} \$

The only option would be to amplify the voltage from your sensor. Alternatively, use a digital sensor you can read directly by I2C or SPI.

Comment: You can't change the internal voltage reference; because it's in the bandgap reference on chip and it's not external. However, ADC's do have external voltage ref pin available.